# How to correctly epoll for ncurses

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, ncurses, epoll

Original question: I wrote some client code that monitors the keyboard presses and the sockfd that the server sends messages to. The problem is after the first message from the server, epoll is no longer triggered by messages from the server. Also, every time I enter key-presses around 10 times, epoll is triggered for sockfd and one pack of characters are read (even though the server has already sent alot of messages). What adds to my confusion is the if I only send one character at a time, epoll is able to react properly. Anything more than one, will have the same result as before (epoll doesn't react).

Edit: I realise that if I set the STDIN_FILENO to non-blocking, I will get messages from the server at appropriate times. However, the program will also go into an infinite loop with STDIN_IN always getting triggered. I guess now the question is how to correctly use epoll with ncurses so that we aren't in an infinite loop.

Here is my code:

How to use:

1. clang++ client.cpp -lncurses -o cli
2. clang++ server.cpp -o ser
3. ./ser 8080
4. open another terminal
5. ./cli 127.0.0.1 8080

I am quite new to epoll so I'm afraid I may have missed something. Please let me know whats wrong with my code!

server.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <errno.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>

#define TO_CLI_BUF_SIZE 32
#define FROM_CLI_BUF_SIZE 8

int main(int argc, char ** argv){

  //seed rand
  srand(time(NULL));

  int sockfd; // socket
  int port; // my port to listen on
  struct sockaddr_in serveraddr; // server's address
  struct sockaddr_in clientaddr;
  socklen_t clientlen;
  int currentAddrMax = 0;
  struct hostent * hostp; //host info
  char * hostaddrp; // host adddr string
  char toClientBuf[TO_CLI_BUF_SIZE];
  char fromClientBuf[FROM_CLI_BUF_SIZE];

  if(argc != 2){
    perror("usage: file <port>");
    exit(1);
  }
  port = atoi(argv[1]);

  // create socket
  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  if(sockfd<0){
    perror("ERROR: opening socket.");
    exit(1);
  }

  bzero((char*) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
  serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  serveraddr.sin_port = htons((unsigned short)port);

  if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0){
    perror("ERROR on bind");
    exit(1);
  }

  bzero(fromClientBuf, FROM_CLI_BUF_SIZE);
  clientlen = sizeof(clientaddr);
  int n = recvfrom(sockfd, fromClientBuf,FROM_CLI_BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &clientaddr, &(clientlen));

  while (1){ 
    bzero(toClientBuf, TO_CLI_BUF_SIZE);
    strcpy(toClientBuf, "alkjhkfqulw8fl128lh1oufo183hf1l\0"); // I want to send 32 TO_CLI_BUF_SIZE
    int amountOfBytes = TO_CLI_BUF_SIZE; // anything greater than 1 will not work
    int n = sendto(sockfd, toClientBuf, amountOfBytes, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clientaddr, clientlen);
    if(n < 0) {
      perror("ERROR in sendto");
      exit(1);
    }

    sleep(1); // sleep 1 sec
  }

  return 0;

}
```

client.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#define FROM_SER_BUF_SIZE 32
#define TO_SER_BUF_SIZE 8

int main(int argc, char **argv){

  int sockfd, portno, n;
  socklen_t serverlen;
  struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
  struct hostent *server;
  char *hostname;

  char toServerBuf[TO_SER_BUF_SIZE];
  char fromServerBuf[FROM_SER_BUF_SIZE];

  if (argc != 3) {
    perror("usage: filename <hostname> <port>\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  hostname = argv[1];
  portno = atoi(argv[2]);

  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  if (sockfd < 0) {
    perror("ERROR: opening sockets\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  server = gethostbyname(hostname);
  if (server == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host as %s\n", hostname);
    exit(0);
  }

  bzero((char *) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
  serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
  (char *)&serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
  serveraddr.sin_port = htons(portno);
  serverlen = sizeof(serveraddr);
  bzero(toServerBuf, TO_SER_BUF_SIZE);
  n = sendto(sockfd, toServerBuf, TO_SER_BUF_SIZE, 0, ( struct sockaddr *) &serveraddr, serverlen);
  if (n < 0){
    perror("ERROR: sendto");
    exit(0);
  }

  if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, serverlen) < 0) { 
    printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n"); 
    exit(0); 
  } 
  fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK); 
  nodelay(stdscr, true);
  fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK); 
  initscr();
  noecho();
  int keyboardtick = 0;
  int servertick = 0;
  int ep = epoll_create1(0);
  struct epoll_event e1,e2, e[2]; // e1 for serverfd, e2 for stdin
  memset(&e1, 0, sizeof(struct epoll_event));
  e1.events = EPOLLIN; 
  e1.data.fd = sockfd;
  epoll_ctl(ep, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, sockfd, &e1); 
  memset(&e2, 0, sizeof(struct epoll_event));
  e2.events = EPOLLIN; 
  e2.data.fd = STDIN_FILENO;
  epoll_ctl(ep, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, STDIN_FILENO, &e2);

  mvprintw(0,0,"ticks from server: %d",servertick);
  mvprintw(2,0,"ticks from keyboard: %d",keyboardtick);
  while (1){ 
    int n = epoll_wait(ep, e, 2, -1);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      if (e[i].data.fd == sockfd) { // from server
        //
        bzero(fromServerBuf, FROM_SER_BUF_SIZE);
        n = recvfrom(sockfd, fromServerBuf, FROM_SER_BUF_SIZE, 0,( struct sockaddr *) &serveraddr, &serverlen);
        if(n < 0) {
          perror("ERROR in recv");
          exit(1);
        }
        servertick+=n;
        mvprintw(0,0,"ticks from server: %d",servertick);
      }else if(e[i].data.fd == STDIN_FILENO){
        char c = getch();
        keyboardtick++;
        mvprintw(2,0,"ticks from keyboard: %d",keyboardtick);
      }
    }
    refresh();
  }


  endwin();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The call to `nodelay` won't work since it precedes `initscr`.  The `getch` call returns an `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
e1.events = EPOLLIN|EPOLLET;
```

You've chosen to use edge-triggered `epoll` events, with this setting.

The epoll manual page goes into a long discussion about what it means, and how to use edge-triggered `epoll` events correctly. You should review that description.

Let's follow along:

```
    int n = epoll_wait(ep, e, 2, -1);

// ...
        n = recvfrom(sockfd, fromServerBuf, FROM_SER_BUF_SIZE, 0,( struct sockaddr *) &serveraddr, &serverlen);
```

If `epoll` was triggered by this socket receiving more than `FROM_SER_BUF_SIZE` bytes, this only reads the first `FROM_SER_BUF_SIZE` bytes -- in other words, the sender was fast enough to send enough data, this will read the first `FROM_SER_BUF_SIZE` bytes just fine. When this returns to `epoll_wait`(), it will wait again. Even though there's more data on the socket to read. That's how edge-triggered `epoll` events work. Your are describing edge-triggered epoll events below:

> The problem is after the first message from the server, epoll is no
>   longer triggered by messages from the server. Also, every time I enter
>   key-presses around 10 times, epoll is triggered for sockfd and one
>   pack of characters are read (even though the server has already sent
>   alot of messages).

Correct. Your `epoll` is edge triggered. The shown logic consumes only the first datagram and calls `epoll` again, even if the socket has more unread datagrams.

> What adds to my confusion is the if I only send one character at a
>   time, epoll is able to react properly. Anything more than one, will
>   have the same result as before (epoll doesn't react).

Correct again. If only one message gets sent, it gets processed by the shown logic, then `epoll` waits again.

An edge-triggered `epoll` will wait until the event occurs on the socket again. Full stop. End of story. If the event already occurred on the socket, an edge-triggered epoll will wait instead of returning immediately. TLDR: if the socket has unread data, `epoll_wait`ing for `POLLIN` will not immediately return. It returns only after more data is received. If ever. That's how edge-triggered `epoll`s work.

If your intent is to use edge-triggered `epoll` logic, the manual page explains that you must use non-blocking sockets, and call `epoll_wait` again only after the socket is completely empty, or full (in other words, repeatedly loop reading or writing stuff until you can't).

Or, don't use edge-triggered `epoll` events. However you ***should*** use non-blocking sockets even with non-edge triggered `epoll`s. You'll have to dig deep into the manual pages, but you will find `epoll`'s incorporating `poll`'s, and `poll`'s incorporating `select`, where you will find the following gem:

```
   Under Linux, select() may report a socket file descriptor as "ready for
   reading", while nevertheless a subsequent read blocks.  This could  for
   example  happen  when  data  has arrived but upon examination has wrong
   checksum and is discarded.  There may be other circumstances in which a
   file  descriptor is spuriously reported as ready.  Thus it may be safer
   to use O_NONBLOCK on sockets that should not block.
```

So, really, for maximum portability, it turns out it doesn't appear to matter, much, whether one uses edge-triggered or level-triggered epoll. To avoid chasing ghosts, the best practice appears to be (based on the available documentation), to always use non-blocking sockets with select/poll/epoll and keep pushing the shovel forward, until it runs out of snow to shovel, and only then summon a select/poll/epoll.

Comment: My bad, EPOLLET was from when I tried to fix the problem but it didn't work. I have tried the default level-triggered and setting the inputs to non-blocking but it still doesn't work. I will updated my code.

Comment: Did you read, carefully, the part where I explained that with non-blocking I/O you must repeatedly read/write until there's no more, and only ***then*** poll for more? Simply flipping the sockets to non-blocking, dropping the `EPOLLET` flag, and leaving everything else, as is, is not going to fix anything.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very familiar with sockets and ncurses so I was confused. It seems that reading everything from the sockets worked. I'm still a little confused whether I have to read all of stdin and if I do would I use getch() (from ncurses) to do that?

Comment: See curses' manual pages. Specifically the first two sentences of `getch`'s manual page? "The getch, wgetch, mvgetch and mvwgetch, routines read a character from the window.  In no-delay mode, if no input is waiting, the value ERR is returned." And then the reference at the end of the manual page to the `curs_inopts` manual page, which describes the "nodelay()" setting. curses will put stdin in no-delay mode for you, so all you have to do is keep `getch`-ing, and polling when nothing is read.